# Can I duplicate an NTFS partition in Windows 10 without 3rd party tools?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, ntfs

I have an external Seagate USB 3 ½TB hard drive with several partitions.

I have two NTFS partitions of identical size on that drive. One has a bunch of files and folders, the other is totally blank and fresh.

I would like to copy the used partition onto the blank one.

I know I could just copy all the files and folders but for this question I would prefer to dupe or mirror the partition so that the copy is as close to identical to the original as possible. Well without creating conflicts when mounting if that would be a possibility.

Can this be done with just the functionality that comes with Windows 10, not using any third party tools?

Comment: just brainstorming here, not sure if these would achieve what you want or even work to begin with : option 1) create a vhd of partition a via hyper-v manager then use vhd2dsk(not exactly an in-built tool) to write it on partition b. option 2) use xcopy to copy everything as it is.

Comment: I doubt it, unless you call the Windows 10 ver 1607 feature of Linux subsystem as not being third party.  People typically use third party apps, possibly including a port of Unix's "dd".  Of course, there are built-in programming languages (using Windows Script Host), so that might be one option.  Other than that, I haven't heard of anything built-in, and I do think I would have heard about something if it was there, so I'm guessing there simply might not be something for this that is part of what is built into (the original release of) Windows 10.

Comment: "Can this be done with just the functionality that comes with Windows 10, not using any third party tools?" - Windows does not have any disk cloning features at this time.  THe Linux Subsystem which is in beta, won't be able to run the (third-party) linux software required to duplicate a volume.  There are dozens of free tools to do this task though.

Comment: I would accept an answer of 'no'. I shall have to be careful in asking a followup question as it's easy to get closed for being a shopping question or off topic for being here rather than on softwarerecs.SE ... In any case my concerns were shown to be valid when I tried just copying the files and folders and then checking afterward I noticed a couple that did not get copied and when adding those I then had a duplicate folder entry. I fixed those errors  but I can't say i'm confident with the copy I now have. Also Explorer shows the two folders have slightly different sizes.